# Is there a way to make Maple 15 graph on the plane?

Tags: maple

I am trying to graph a parametric equation on $\mathbb{R}^2$, but Maple keeps giving me an $\mathbb{R}^3$ curve.

Here is what I did

```
L2 := spacecurve([cos(t), cos(3*t), 0], t = -1 .. 0, axes = framed)
display(L2)
```

Now I was also stupid enough to use "planecurve" and Maple doesn't recognize it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare the 3d spacecurve,

```
plots:-spacecurve([cos(t),cos(3*t),0],t=-1..0,axes=box,
              labels=[x,y,``],orientation=[-90,0,0]);
```

[image]

with the 2d curve,

```
plot([cos(t),cos(3*t),t=-1..0],axes=box);
```

[image]

That calling sequence of the `plot` command is called parametric. See the
help-page ?plots,parametric or [online](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=plot/parametric).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specifically need Maple, you can
[plot it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%3Dcos%28t%29%2C+y%3Dcos%283%2at%29%2C+t+%3D+-1++to+0)
using WolframAlpha.